# How to create a snap that relies on docker

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I'm new to the Snappy community and have a question regarding building a snap that relies on the Docker framework. I have a test Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/skawaii/docker-whaley/). I can build and install the snap just fine, but I get this error whenever I try to run it (via `whaley.speak`):

```
(amd64)ubuntu@ubuntu-snappy:~$ whaley.speak
/apps/whaley.sideload/IIDeccTbeLdT/bin/speak.sh: 2: /apps/whaley.sideload/IIDeccTbeLdT/bin/speak.sh: docker: Operation not permitted
```

My snapcraft.yaml file is:

```
name: whaley
version: 1.0
vendor: Jason Cooper <>
summary: A test snap of a docker image.
description: A test snap of a docker image.
icon: whale.png
frameworks:
  - docker
binaries:
  speak:
    exec: bin/speak.sh
    caps:
      - docker_client
      - networking
parts:
  glue:
    plugin: copy
    files:
      speak.sh: bin/speak.sh
```

`speak.sh` simply contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
docker run skawaii/docker-whaley
```

Any thoughts on why I can use the `docker` command via my shell script? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is very old version, many thing changed in snap. Could you update the question with results from last release?